# How to check if fields are empty on all rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What will I do with my jquery dialog? Pop up notification that fields are empty have just appeared on the first row empty fields. But on succeeding rows, this is not functioning though fields are empty.

```
function Save() {

      var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 
      var tdFirstName = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
      var tdLastName = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
      var tdAge = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
      var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");

      tdFirstName.html(tdFirstName.children("input[type=text]").val());
      tdLastName.html(tdLastName.children("input[type=text]").val());
      tdAge.html(tdAge.children("input[type=text]").val());

      tdFirstName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='" + tdFirstName.html() + "'/>");
      tdLastName.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='" + tdLastName.html() + "'/>");
      tdAge.html("<input type='text' id='txtEmail' value='" + tdAge.html() + "'/>");

      if ($('#txtName').val() == "" || $('#txtPhone').val() == "" || $('#txtEmail').val() == "") {

            alert('Please complete the field');

      } else {

          $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
          $('.btnSave').attr('disabled','disabled');
          $('.btnEdit').removeAttr('disabled');
          $('.btnDelete').removeAttr('disabled');

          tdFirstName.find('input').attr('disabled', 'true');
          tdLastName.find('input').attr('disabled', 'true');
          tdAge.find('input').attr('disabled', 'true');

      }

      $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
      $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
      $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);

    };
```

Comment: You should show the markup you're traversing with jQuery. Chances are there are simpler ways to do what you're doing. Also, `bind()` is deprecated. Consider switching to `on()`.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52702764/edit), then click on the button that looks like `[<>]` and produce a [mcve] with relevant HTML and jQuery version